# How to create blur effect to all the scene except for one object (focus on that object)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blur

I want to create a blur effect similar to the picture below:
[image]

the picture is taken from this site:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-blur-specific-layers-only.555520/

I tried the post-processing profile and played around with the depth of field in the post-processing volume but it blurs all the scene.

I came across a [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDG4XR-83X4) that explains how to implement similar results to what I am looking for but things have changed drastically in the settings. For example, at 1:57 (minute and 57 seconds) he clicks on `Add Additional Camera Data` which I am struggling to find in the latest versions of LWRP.

I am using Unity version 2019.2.9f1

How can I achieve the result in the picture above? (Blurring all the scene except for one object)

Your guidance will be appreciated.

**NOTE:** My project is in VR using SteamVR and VRTK

Comment: Basically exactly as it says in the description to your image: Use different layers and different cameras, blur everything for the main camera. Set the "focused" GameObject on a layer "focus". the main camera doesn't render this layer (culling mask). The focuseCamera only renders the "focus" layer with clear flag "dont clear" on top of the main camera. Done ;)

Comment: @derHugo how do I set focused GameObject? is it in the inspector setting of the gameObject? or the camera? because I can't seem to find this setting

Comment: You simply change the layer of according object to the layer "Focus"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Though your question is a bit broad I took some time to show you how it can be done.

---

First of all you will need to import the `Post Processing` package via the [PackageManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html)

<kbd>Window</kbd> → <kbd>PackageManager</kbd>

[image]

Make sure to be in the `All Packages` view, search for `post`, find the `Post Processing` package and hit <kbd>Install</kbd>

[image]

---

Now first of all go to the Layer settings (<kbd>Layers</kbd> → <kbd>Edit Layers</kbd>)

[image]

and add **two** additional Layers: e.g. `PostProcessing` and `Focused`

[image]

Now to the cameras. Afaik it makes no difference whether you are in VR or not, usually you have one `MainCamera` that is moved along with your headset. If there should be two of them in your project setup just repeat the same steps for the second camera.

1. Make sure the `MainCamera` doesn't render the two added Layers → remove them from the `Culling Mask`

[image]

2. Add a new Camera `FocusCamera` as child to the existing `MainCamera`. This way it is automatically moved along with the main Camera.

   <kbd>RightClick on `MainCamera`</kbd> &rightarrow <kbd>Camera</kbd>

   [image]

   It should have all the settings equal to the `MainCamera` **except**:

   - `Clear Flags` : <kbd>Don't Clear</kbd>
     If you set it to `Depth Only` the focused object will always be rendered on top of everything, even if it is actually behind other objects in 3D space. You decide which effect you want here ;)
   - `CullingMask` : **only** <kbd>Focused</kbd>
   - `Depth` : Anything higher than the `MainCamera` so this camera is rendered on top of it
   - Make sure to remove the `AudioListener` component.

   [image]
   [image]
3. Finally add a new `PostProcessingVolume` to the scene. I would add it as child to the `FocusCamera`! Why? - Because this way it is automatically disabled together with the `FocusCamera`!

   <kbd>RightClick</kbd> on `FocusCamera` → <kbd>3D Object</kbd> → <kbd>Post Processing Volume</kbd>

   [image]

   Set its `Layer` to the added `PostProcessing`

   [image]

   enable `Is Global` so the distance to the volume doesn't matter and add a new profile by hitting <kbd>new</kbd> → <kbd>Unity</kbd> → <kbd>Depth of field</kbd>

   In your case you want to overwrite the `Focus Distance` so check the box on the left and set a value close to the camera like e.g. `0.5`

   [image]

Until now nothing has really changed in your scene.

Now go to the `MainCamera` and, a component `PostProcessingLayer` and set the `Layer` to our added layer <kbd>PostProcessing</kbd>

[image]

Now everything should be blurred in your scene!

Almost ready to go! Now Disable the `FocusCamera` and add this script to it

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class FocusSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string FocusedLayer = "Focused";

    private GameObject currentlyFocused;
    private int previousLayer;

    public void SetFocused(GameObject obj)
    {
        // enables this camera and the postProcessingVolume which is the child
        gameObject.SetActive(true);

        // if something else was focused before reset it
        if (currentlyFocused) currentlyFocused.layer = previousLayer;

        // store and focus the new object
        currentlyFocused = obj;

        if (currentlyFocused)
        {
            previousLayer = currentlyFocused.layer;
            currentlyFocused.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer(FocusedLayer);
        }
        else
        {
            // if no object is focused disable the FocusCamera
            // and PostProcessingVolume for not wasting rendering resources
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    // On disable make sure to reset the current object
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        if (currentlyFocused) currentlyFocused.layer =previousLayer;

        currentlyFocused = null;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to focus a certain GameObject on runtime by changing its layer to the `Focused` layer we added, the only one that is rendered by the `FocusCamera`. So this object will be rendered on top of the image without any blur effect!

---

For demonstration I just added this simple script to every cube object in order to enable focus on mouse enter and disable it on mouse exit:

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class FocusMe : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private FocusSwitcher focus;

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        focus.SetFocused(gameObject);
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        // reset the focus
        // in the future you should maybe check first
        // if this object is actually the focused one currently
        focus.SetFocused(null);
    }
}
```

And here is what it looks like

[image]

---

as said I don't know exactly what your VR setup looks like. If you have to MainCameras simply add two child cameras to them. You still will need only one PostProcessingVolume and only one `FocusSwitcher` so you would probably move them to another object and handle the camera disabling etc differently but I hope the idea gets clear enough.

Comment: thank you a lot for the massive efforts your putting here, really appreciate it sir, THANKS

Comment: I cannot get this to work. All I get when I turn on the FocusCamera is the focused object on a black background. Despite the clear flags being set to "Don't Clear" it appears that the image from the main camera is completely cleared before rendering FocusCamera's image over it.

Comment: Great efforts here, but in order to function I had to make `FocusSwitcher` object `public` and to assign the new camera to it.

Comment: @muaz it doesn't need to be `public` if it is serialized and assigned via the Inspector ;)

Comment: honestly amazing answer, with all those screenshots and everything

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate camera for objects you don't want to blur and set a higher depth value. 
Set the `ClearFlags` to depth only and in the `CullingMask` select the layer of that one object(or more objects). Obviously you would require to have a different layer for unblurred objects.

Comment: creating two cameras is what gets me confused because I am using VR and not sure how can I create two cameras for the same VR headset, I will try to implement your solution but if you can give me further guidance, it will help me a lot.

Comment: @mazin as far my VR experience, you must be having two cameras in your scene, one for rightEye and one for leftEye. Now for your blur background effect you will actually need 2 more cameras with same `Viewport Rect` values as main rightEye and LeftEye cameras respectively. but different positions as needed for vr.
i would suggest you to make the new cameras(that are rendering the unblurred object/objects) the child of respective rightEye and leftEye cameras and set there `position` and `rotation` to `0,0,0`. Hope it helps!