# Why Post-process Volume is not exist after imported the Post Processing package?

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing

In my editor in the menu I did : Window > Package Manager > Post Processing Stack > Download > Import

Then he asked me to make a backup and he did some API changes.

[image: Pack manager post processing]

Then I'm trying to walk through this tutorial answer :

[How to create blur effect to all the scene except for one object (focus on that object)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188747/how-to-create-blur-effect-to-all-the-scene-except-for-one-object-focus-on-that)

At some point, he describes how to add to the child camera a Post-process Volume but it does not exist on my side :

[image: How to add the post process volume in the tutorial]

And this is in my editor the post-process volume not exist :

[image: post process volume is not existing]

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.0/manual/Quick-start.html) post processing volume is a component added to the gameobject. Maybe an outdated tutorial?

Comment: "To enable post-processing in your scene, add the Rendering > Post Process Layer component to the Main Camera GameObject"

Comment: Hehe thanks for referring to my (old) answer ;) It looks like you are using a different version of post processing - note that my answer was using Unity 2019.3 and Post-Processing 2.1.7 ... yours says 1.0.4 .. which Unity version are you using?

Comment: you need to keep up with the outdated answers mr. Der hugo ;) just kidding

Comment: @rustyBucketBay in contrary OP is using the outdated Post-Processing ;) my answer uses the newer Post-Processing V2