# Is there a way to apply bloom to a specific object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've currently noticed that, if i uncheck the "is Global" checkbox on the Bloom Effect of a Post Processing Volume, even thought I adjusted my layer to affect one in particular, the Bloom doesnt apply to that layer I've set in the P-p layer. In fact, it doesn't apply at all. Either it sets bloom for everything in the scene, or it doesn't.

Extras: I have no Pipeline asset, maybe thats the issue, but I've tried to setting one LRP (because for some reason URP in my 2019.2.17f1 version doenst exist) and it just breaks all my materials that i use for Particle Systems (Particles/Standard Unlit) even if i upgrade them for LRP materials.

Any ideas? If it's possible to deliver a solution to both these problems excellent, but the main one is the title question.

Comment: Please note that the [_"Lightweight Render Pipeline"_ is now known as the _"Universal Render Pipeline"_](https://unity.com/srp/universal-render-pipeline), both don't exist by default in a project (unless you explicity create a project targeting said pipeline) and have to be [added via a package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.lightweight@5.10/manual/installing-lwrp-into-an-existing-project.html)....

Comment: ...URP has been available [since Unity 2018.1](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.lightweight@3.0/manual/index.html#how-to-use-lightweight-pipeline).   _"and it just breaks all my materials"_ - yes that is to be expected sadly.  There is an upgrade wizard but it generally only works with standard shaders

Comment: ooooh all right, does it work the same way as the urp in later versions?

Comment: LWRP could be thought of as the _"beta"_ version (or at least represents a mid-life crisis in the Unity Marketing Department ;)  )  of URP and for all intensive purposes operates the same way as LWRP.  As is anything with Unity though, any new version adds new features with the possibility that some are _breaking changes._

Comment: Kind of related to [How to create blur effect to all the scene except for one object (focus on that object)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188747/how-to-create-blur-effect-to-all-the-scene-except-for-one-object-focus-on-that/59190097#59190097) right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

**Note:** The *"camera stacking"* approach mentioned here applies only to Unity *URP*. For the Unity *Built-in Render Pipeline* or Unity versions [**prior** to 2019.3.0f3](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@11.0/manual/requirements.html) you can achieve a similar effect with [`RenderTexture`s](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html).  Though Unity *HDRP* has no explicit *"camera stacking"* feature it does allow for the same net effect via the HDRP-specific *[Graphics Compositor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@10.2/manual/Compositor-User-Guide.html)*.

---

> *"Is there a way to apply bloom to a specific object?"*

You could take a leaf out of *[Unity camera stacking](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.2/manual/camera-stacking.html)* whereby one set of objects are rendered by one camera and another set with a *different camera*. The results of each camera rendering are merged together automatically by Unity and presented to the screen.

But don't take my word for it, this is what Unity has to say:

> In the Universal Render Pipeline (URP), you use Camera Stacking to layer the output of multiple Cameras and create a single combined output. Camera Stacking allows you to create effects such as a 3D model in a 2D UI, or the cockpit of a vehicle.  *[Tell me more...](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.2/manual/camera-stacking.html)*

...and (my emphasis):

> A Camera Stack **overrides the output of the Base Camera** with the combined output of all the Cameras in the Camera Stack. As such, anything that you can do with the output of a Base Camera, you can do with the output of a Camera Stack. For example, you can render a Camera Stack to a given render target, **apply post-process effects**, and so on. *[Tell me more...](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.2/manual/camera-stacking.html)*

When you consider that each camera has the potential for its own rendering settings (including bloom) the solution is clear:

1. ensure there are two cameras in the scene, say **My Default Camera** and **Bloomin' Camera**
2. create a custom layer called *"Bloom"*
3. assign whatever objects you want to be rendered with a bloom to layer **Bloom**
4. setup the camera stack as per *["Adding a Camera to a Camera Stack"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.2/manual/camera-stacking.html)*.

**My Default Camera** should be set to *"Base"*:

[image]

**Bloomin' Camera** should be set to overlay:

[image]

Add **Bloomin' Camera** to **My Default Camera** **Stack** settings:

[image]

5. ensure that the [Culling mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) for **My Default Camera** has the **Bloom** layer *unticked*.  This ensures that the objects to be bloomed are only drawn **once** on the **Bloom** layer
6. ensure that the [Culling mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) for **Bloomin' Camera** has a *single ticked entry* for the **Bloom** layer and **nothing else**. You don't want to double-up on rendering otherwise you will get funky and undesirable z-order effects apart from hurting game performance.  Other layers will be rendered by **My Default Camera**.
7. apply bloom effects to camera **Bloomin' Camera**
8. run game, celebrate

Comment: let me try this one out

Comment: when i do this, the thing that happens is that the things that are in the "bloom" layer do not appear because (i suppose) they are rendered by the other camara, how do i use both cams for the game?

Comment: @SirPolo so **My Default Camera** should be the _[base camera](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.2/manual/camera-stacking.html)_ **Render Type** should be set to _Base_; **Bloomin' Camera**'s **Render Type** should be set to _Overlay_

Comment: i thought so, but i am not seeing a render type, https://prnt.sc/23hoz1c

Comment: @SirPolo https://imgur.com/a/pqGkC0W.  What version of Unity, URP are your running?

Comment: 2019.2.17f1, and i currently dont have any URP asset set, as upgrading materials to the LRP breaks my materials; unless i can try and make some specific for the LRP

Comment: @SirPolo Yes for URP you need to be running **2019.3.0f3** as a minimum sadly which I completely understand if you don't wish to upgrade.  If you don't want to use URP which is again understandable you can use `RenderTexture`s with the _Built-in Render Pipeline_ and merge the results manually.  Please see my recent edit to my answer above.   You mentioned _"LRP"_, now if you mean out-of-the-box Unity and especially versions prior to **2018**, then _LWRP, URP_ and _HDRP_ did not yet exist then check out my `RenderTexture` suggestion.  Ah...things were simpler back then ;)

Comment: great detailed answer. But i think you have to set your base camera to only render the bloom GameObjects, otherwise the overlay camera will apply bloom event to GameObjects that are not on it's layermask but have emissive materials, atleast that is what i experienced.

Comment: @nka_Zz close but you did remind me of something.  I neglected to mention that under URP there will be at least **one** _URP Render Pipeline Asset_ pointing to at least **one** _URP Renderer_.  The default renderer will draw all objects regardless of layer so that needs to be changed.  Like dual cameras, we just need to change the default renderer to ignore the blooming layer and disable post processing; then add another renderer that is essentially the reverse of the former - render just the bloom layer **but** now we want to tell it to add post processing

Answer (score 1):

The is global might sound confusing at first. Ultimately it does not mean where to apply the post processing effect, but when to apply the effect. If it is set to Global, it will always be applied, otherwise you can set a layer and a border that triggers the effect.

The general approach is to only set emission to materials where you want the effect to take place. If your Materials are to dark otherwise you should adjust the ambient lighting settings.

Atleast in URP there are some work arounds for older versions [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0weJA2Gd5bw), but afaik this does not work in 2020.3 since they made some changes on URP and the camera system.

edit: on the video Chris Hull
Chris Hull game an answer for how to do it with the new system

> @Mezzanine  Add your actual game objects to a created bloom layer.
> Create two cameras and set one of them to cull everything except that
> bloom layer you made. Set the other to only cull the bloom layer. Then
> you can set your camera to overlay and it will be added to the other.
> You can then use separate post process stacks on these cameras. Note
> that you can only bloom objects in the background with this technique
> as if you add bloom to an overlay camera, for some reason it just adds
> bloom to everything rather than just the things in that camera view.
> Doesn't make much sense and makes the purpose of the layers redundant
> in my opinion. If you can find a way to add post process to the
> overlay camera before it is added to the final image, to do let me
> know.

i have not tested that yet, but i presume it's still valid.

Comment: thing is, it is applied globally too, like it affects every layer even thought i set it to affect one in particular. how do i fix that?

Comment: yes it will affect everything, since layer does not mean that it only applies to that one layer, but that this one layer is the trigger to use or not use the post processing

Comment: all right i see; going back to the post, is there a way to apply it to a specific object?

Comment: Ah, sorry I did not notice you started to mention _camera stacking_ near the end.  My answer then essentially builds upon yours. :)